# How can i create an inter which accepts 18 digits, in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

How can i create a database table column, which accepts an inter of 18 characters length and similarly how can i create a database column of string of length 12 characters. I am using the postgresql database.

Comment: Can't you just set limitations via the model?

Comment: EG: `validates :something, length: { maximum: 12 }`

Answer (score 1):

Int's have a max length of 11 characters in the db.

I believe if you make the migration that of a bigint then you could set a limit in the model as kuwantum suggests.

https://gist.github.com/stream7/1069589/e03f2b99a89ffad49cb7c9959e640ea1ac9d9ff1